# Implicit differentiation featuring trig functions

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

How would I solve the following question that is troubling me.

The question is

> Find an equation for the tangent line to the graph of $x+\sin(y-2x)=1$ at point $(1,2)$

I did the following using the chain rule

$1+\cos(y-2x)(\frac{dy}{dx})(-2)$

then I simplified to $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2}{cos(y-2x)}$ so I plugged in $x$ and $y $ and got $\cos(0)$ on the denominator which is $1$.

But I am unsure if I did that part correctly my final answer is $y-2=2(x-1)$

Comment: It is rather $1+\cos(y-2x)(\frac{dy}{dx}-2)=0$. Watch the parenthesis!

Comment: I mean I used the chain rule so its dy/dx(-2)

Comment: I did use the chain rule too... The derivative of $y-2x$ is $(\frac{dy}{dx}-2)$. Not $\frac{dy}{dx}(-2)=-2\frac{dy}{dx}$. Can you see the difference now?

Comment: @julien: Make the OP, the answer. It seems that he/she does not know my approach. I 'll remove my answer.

Comment: @BabakS. Hi Babak! I will wait to see if he understands my comments first.

Comment: I admit I do not understand the comment.

Comment: For the chain rule, you want to multiply $\cos(y-2x)$ by the derivative of $y-2x$. This is $\frac{dy}{dx}-2$ and not $\frac{dy}{dx}(-2)$. What do you not understand? Say $y=\sin x$ for instance. Then the derivative of $y-2x=\sin x -2x$ is $\cos x-2$, and not $(\cos x)(-2)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what is being suggested is that:

Differentiating $$x+\sin(y-2x)=1$$ by using the chain rule should result in:

$$1 + \cos(y - 2x)\left(\frac{dy}{dx} - 2\right) = 0$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{-1 + 2\cos(y - 2x)}{\cos(y - 2x)},$$ then evaluate at point $(1,2)$

Comment: The OP does not understand that the derivative of $y-2x$ is $\frac{dy}{dx}-2$, and not $\frac{dy}{dx}(-2)$. Maybe you can find better words than me.

Comment: I see now I was confused between subtraction sign and the negative sign which is used to multiply.

Comment: Yes, signs can get confusing...we all slip up, with algebra, at times. Now you need only find dy/dx evaluated at $(1, 2)$, and write the tangent line as you did in your earlier problem.

Comment: I see that distributive property was also used.

Comment: Yes, indeed! Does the result make sense?

Comment: yes It does I plugged in x and y and got $y-2=1(x-1)$ because $-1+2cos(0)+cos(2-2(1)$ $cos(0)=1$

Comment: Yup...that's right!